# How to correct crop image using FFMPEG&XILINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, xilinx

I use AWS vt1 with Xilinx SDK and FFMPEG. All from the AWS box with pre-built SDK and so on.
I need to extract frames from fullHD but scale it to 480p
I stuck with it. Could someone help with the correct options?

I have this Python-based code:

```
        # If the video is greater than 480p, resize the frames to 480p
        if height > 480:
            command = [
                ffmpeg_path,
                '-c:v', 'mpsoc_vcu_h264',
                '-i', temp_video,
                '-filter_complex',
                'multiscale_xma=outputs=1: out_1_width=848: out_1_height=480: out_1_rate=half:[b]; [b]xvbm_convert[b1]',
                '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
                '-ss', str(median_time),
                '-map', '[b1]',
                '-vframes', '1',
                '-q:v', '2',
                '-f', 'image2pipe',
                '-vcodec', 'mjpeg',
                '-y', '-'
            ]
        else:  # Preserve the original resolution
            command = [
                ffmpeg_path,
                '-c:v', 'mpsoc_vcu_h264',
                '-i', temp_video,
                '-vf', 'xvbm_convert',
                '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
                '-ss', str(median_time),
                '-vframes', '1',
                '-q:v', '2',
                '-f', 'image2pipe',
                '-vcodec', 'mjpeg',
                '-y', '-'
            ]
            output = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True)
            frame = output.stdout
```

The second option with '-vf', 'xvbm_convert', work perfectly.
But the issue with the first.

Answer (score 0):

find the solution myself ))
so if someone needs similar further, the correct command is:

```
command = [
                    ffmpeg_path,
                    '-c:v', 'mpsoc_vcu_h264',
                    '-i', temp_video,
                    '-vf', 'xvbm_convert,scale=-1:480', 
                    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
                    '-ss', str(median_time),
                    '-vframes', '1',
                    '-q:v', '2',
                    '-f', 'image2',
                    '-vcodec', 'mjpeg',
                    '-y', frame_path
                ]
```